# How to create a custom preboot authentication screen for windows?

Tags: windows-7, boot, encryption, truecrypt, bootloader

Back in days of Truecrypt there was a feature called "preboot authentication screen".
See http://www.groovypost.com/howto/fake-error-msg-boot-truecrypt/

It was possible to show a simple boot loader message. The password could be type in hidden (no password field, no cursor). Just a blank screen with the bootloader message.

Question: how could I create such a "bootloader" screen nowadays, for GPT  win7 drive?

- Truecrypt - is deprecated, and not supporting GPT.
- BitLocker does not seem to have that feature of a plain bootloader screen
- VeraCrypt - developed from TC, but does it support such a screen without having to encrypt the whole drive?

What else?
I don't want to encrypt my entire primary drive, just add such a bootloader password screen not being able to bypass. (of course one could bypass it by exchanging the drive - but that's ok and wanted).

Comment: Many bios' support a boot password.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: Yes, I can only create a password that prevents accessing the BIOS itself. But not for general startup.